# Count the referrals in excel

Tags: excel

I have a email column and referral(email) column in excel. I want referral numbers that identifies how many people each person has referred. How to do it in excel?

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: seems like a simple countif should do what you want?

Comment: @Chrisvdberge tried =COUNTIF(H6:H1608,"="&A6) where H is referral email and A being normal email. But everything gives 0

Comment: remove the "="&

Comment: @Chrisvdberge =COUNTIF(H:H,"="&A6) working. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=COUNTIF(H:H,"="&A6) is working. Comparing all the referrals(H:H) with each email (A) and appending count to every respective column.